# Google Now on the LG G2

Tags: google-now, lg, lg-g2

Yesterday I bought a new LG G2 device and I wanted to turn on the Google Now feature, sadly, my Google Search app settings does not show any sign of Now switch. How can I turn on the Google Now

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Have you installed the updated Search app? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox

Comment: Sure, I've installed it!

Answer (score 2):

See if Google search is somehow disabled in the list of apps. Alternatively, ensure that the latest version of [Google Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox) has been installed in your device.

I am assuming of course, that Google Now is a supported feature in your country.

Comment: I did a factory reset and it suddenly work itself out!

Comment: Excellent. Glad it worked out.